# Logical Equivalences into english sentence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I express each of the sentence below as an English sentence?

I believe that I have problems a. b and c down (can you please make sure it is correct) but I am not sure about problem d because of the (~) being outside of the parenthesis. Does it make the problem for d become $(\neg P  ∧ \neg Q \rightarrow \neg R)$?

Let P : I catch Pokemon

Let Q: I drive

Let R: I have fun

(a) ∼ P = I do not catch pokemon

(b) P ∧ R = I catch pokemon and have fun

(c) Q →∼ P = If I drive then I do not catch pokemon

(d) ∼ (P ∧ Q → R) = If I do  not catch pokemon and I do not drive then I do not have fun

Comment: Please adjust the bracket for the last question,

Comment: (d) must be : $(\sim P \land \sim Q) \to \sim R$.

Comment: Where is the second parenthesis? It can change the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

When $\sim$ is outside parenthesis you can use "It is false that...(expression inside parenthesis)".

In your case:

"It is false that If I both catch Pokemon and drive, then I have fun."

Comment: Why is the statement that I had proposed wrong?                                        ∼ (P ∧ Q → R) = If I do not catch pokemon and I do not drive then I do not have fun

Comment: If you know how to do truth tables, you can check that $\sim (P\wedge Q\rightarrow R)$ is not same as $\sim P \wedge \sim Q\rightarrow \sim R$.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting a feel for the truth tables behind them. In the case of D: [Truth table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO0vv.png)
Now you can try finding a sentence that satisfies the table. This is also a good way to  check your work.